# WPF video recording

Tags: wpf, video-capture

Im building a WPF 4.0 application and I want to include the ability to have a web-cam beside the PC running the app and I want to be able to record a video message. I cannot find any articles on this, and it seems like it might be a bit tricky...

Has anyone had any experience with this or know where to start?

Comment: Check out WPf Media Kit at http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/. The sample application can use a webcam out of the box - might be a good start in finding out how to record from one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lots of good stuff out there, eg:

http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/

http://khason.net/blog/webcam-control-with-wpf-or-how-to-create-high-framerate-player-with-directshow-by-using-interopbitmap-in-wpf-application/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cmarchal/archive/2006/08/25/724224.aspx

EDIT: for recording: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uberdemo/archive/2008/03/27/capturing-a-webcam-stream-to-a-wmv-file-from-within-a-wpf-application.aspx

http://videorendererelement.codeplex.com/

Comment: none of these are recoding a video, just displaying the video and capturing a single image from the webcam